# Get error when use solid-i18next useTransContext function in child component

Tags: typescript

Import solid-i18next functon in father page the t function works correct

```
import { useTransContext } from "@mbarzda/solid-i18next";
import LanguageSwitcher from "@SRC/components/LanguageSwitcher";

export const frmSettings = function(props: propsSettings) {
  const [t] = useTransContext();
  return (
   <>
    <LanguageSwitcher />
   </>
 )
}
```

The component LanguageSwitcher has typescript like:

```
import { useTransContext, Trans } from "@mbarzda/solid-i18next";
import { DEBUG } from "@SRC/data/config";
import translate from "@SRC/locales/translate";
import i18next from "i18next";

const LanguageSwitcher = () => {
  const [t, { changeLanguage }] = useTransContext();
  function handleLanguageChange(event) {
    translate.lng = event.target.value;
    changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        class="select select-bordered w-full max-w-xs"
        value={translate.lng}
        onChange={handleLanguageChange}
      >
        <option value="en">en</option>
        <option value="indiaEn">indiaEn</option>
        <option value="zh">zhongwen</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

and when i run this page ,will get an error:( Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)() is undefined ) in component LanguageSwitcher

debug error image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0C5D.png)

I hope the child component works correct.